# Uikit Icons in Rails not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6, getuikit

I have decided to use UiKit in my Rails 6 project and it works great. However, I just cannot get the icons to work. I checked a bunch of web resources but nothing solves the problem.

I'm using
- Rails 6
- webpacker (standard w. Rails6)
- yarn (standard w. Rails6)
- jquery (for custom coding)

In my view I am doing nothing but trying to show the icon:

```
<span uk-icon="heart">tests</span>
<a href="" uk-icon="icon: heart">test</a>
```

**Crickets. Nothing**.

I have UiKit installed with Yarn:
$: yarn list
...

```
├─ uikit-icons@0.5.0
│  ├─ @types/react@^16.9.11
│  └─ react@^16.11.0
├─ uikit@3.4.1
```

My application.js looks like this:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
require("uikit")
require("uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons")
```

This does not throw an error. I tried the following:

```
require("uikit-icons")
```

and it resulted in a webpacker compiling error and an error message in the js console:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'uikit-icons'
```

I tried adding

```
// loads the Icon plugin
UIkit.use(Icons);
```

that results in JS error (again, not using react. I am using jquery).

I even added the cdn url for the icons:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-beta.42/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
```

Nix. Silence. Nothing.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Still at a loss here. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are only requiring the UIkit library not assigning it to anything so it's throwing an error if you try to use it.

This worked for me:

```
const UIkit = require('uikit')
const Icons = require('uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons')

UIkit.use(Icons);
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to make the switch from uikit to bootstrap. It wasn't too late and bootstrap just seems a little simpler to me. Appreciate your answer.